# React native android app not getting branch referral data after play store install

Tags: android, react-native, branch.io

We have a react native app, compiled into both android and ios.  We are using branch.io to track installs via different links and route the user to different places.  The ios app works great in all scnearios.

For the android app, it works in every test case listed on the site (most of which are install the app but don't open it, then click the link, or vice versa), but when the link directs the user to the play store, and they download it from there, the link is not working.

I have seen 3 cases
1. It works fine (rare)
2. It doesn't work at all, and no data comes through
3. Params come through as `+clicked_branch_link:false +is_first_session:true`

I am using the latest version of react-native-branch from npm

So far, email support from branch has been unresponsive, and the one response I received was of no help

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I was using react-native-branch v2.2.4 from NPM

I tested the following cases:

1. [Works] Click the branch link then install the app
2. [Works] Install the app from an APK but don't open it, then click the link
3. [Works] Install the app from the store THEN click the link
4. [Broken] Click the link to install through the app store

Turns out, the issue was resolved by removing the following lines from the AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <!-- Branch install referrer tracking (optional) -->
    <receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I was running into a similar issue, and your solution worked! However, I do get the params but can't differentiate if it was a new install? Do you have any ideas about it?

Answer (score 0):

In order for all deep linking edge cases to work, you need to confirm that:

1) You import the Branch packages into your `MainApplication.java`

```
import io.branch.rnbranch.RNBranchPackage;
import io.branch.referral.Branch;
```

2) Add RNBranchPackage to the package list in `MainApplication.java`

```
@Override
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            new RNBranchPackage(), // <-- add this
```

3) Override onCreate() in `MainApplication.java`

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
}
```

4) Import Branch into your `MainActivity`:

```
import io.branch.rnbranch.*;
import android.content.Intent;
```

5) Branch is initialized in the `onStart()` of your `MainActivity`:

```
protected void onStart() {
          super.onStart();
          RNBranchModule.initSession(getIntent().getData(), this);
      }
```

6) `onNewIntent()` is overidden in the `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
      public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
          setIntent(intent);
      }
```

Note that this is under the assumption your `MainActivity` is the main launcher activity. Please reference:
https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/react-native/#android_1

Comment: I have done all of that, and followed all of the instructions, including enabling 100% matching